# Indexing dependent subqueries in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a complex query that does produce the results I want, abet very slowly.  (like 600 seconds!)

```
SELECT * 
FROM   clients 
WHERE  type = 'gold' 
       AND state IN( 'TX', 'WV', 'NV', 'IL' ) 
AND phone not in 
       (
          select phone 
          from clients 
          group by phone
          having count(*) > 1
       )
AND cell not in 
       (
          select cell 
          from clients 
          group by cell
          having count(*) > 1
        )
```

EXPLAIN SELECT Gives me:

```
id, select_type, table,  Possible_keys,  key,  key_len,  ref,  rows,  Extra
1, PRIMARY, clients, ALL, ndxCLients_state,IGA_Count, , , , 128070, Using where
2, DEPENDENT SUBQUERY, clients, ALL, , , , , 128070, Using temporary; Using filesort
3, DEPENDENT SUBQUERY, clients, index, , idx_Cell, 258, , 3, Using index
```

I am struggling with what to do here.  I think it is trying to tell me that I am need of an index on the phone field.  Using mysql workbench I indexed the phone field.  What am I missing here?

Comment: **You need to show us the table and index definitions.**  Diagnosing slow queries requires full table and index definitions, not just a description or paraphrase.  Maybe your tables are defined poorly.  Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly.  Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did.   Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell.

Comment: Thanks Andy.  I feared that.    Ill have to come up with a trim and compact version as I am learning on a big ugly production database.

Comment: use https://www.sqlfiddle.com and put just clients table with small dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using LEFT JOIN is often better than `IN` and `NOT IN`

```
SELECT c.*
FROM clients c
LEFT JOIN (SELECT phone
           FROM clients
           GROUP BY phone
           HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) p
ON c.phone = p.phone
LEFT JOIN (SELECT cell
           FROM clients
           GROUP BY cell
           HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) cl
ON c.cell = p.cell
WHERE p.phone IS NULL AND cl.cell IS NULL
AND type = 'gold'
AND state IN( 'TX', 'WV', 'NV', 'IL' )
```

Make sure you have indexes on `phone` and `cell`. They might or might not be used for the JOINs, depending on whether the indexes on `type` and/or `state` are more useful, but they'll be used to optimize the `GROUP BY` in the subqueries.